# BlocProvider bug in Flutter and how to fix it

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

So I am having some issues on the BlocProvider front. This is the issue I am getting:

EDIT: Added DrinkBloc and changed snippet on main page:

**Full code**

```
   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Building entire food list scaffold");
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("FoodList")),
      //THE BLOCPROVIDER 
      body: BlocProvider(
      //the issue might be that it is DrinkBloc(), but I have 2 separate tables, one after another
        create: (BuildContext context) => DrinkBloc(),
        child: Column(children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              Text('Drinks'),
              Divider(),
              IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (BuildContext context) => DrinkForm())))
            ],
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              child: BlocConsumer<DrinkBloc, List<Drink>>(
                builder: (context, drinkList) {
                  return ListView.separated(
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      print("drinkList: $drinkList");

                      Drink drink = drinkList[index];
                      return ListTile(
                          title: Text("${drink.name}",
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30)),
                          onTap: () => showDrinkDialog(context, drink, index));
                    },
                    itemCount: drinkList.length,
                    separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                        Divider(color: Colors.black),
                  );
                },
                listener: (BuildContext context, drinkList) {},
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              Text('Foods'),
              Divider(),
              IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (BuildContext context) => FoodForm())))
            ],
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              child: BlocConsumer<FoodBloc, List<Food>>(
                builder: (context, foodList) {
                  return ListView.separated(
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      print("foodList: $foodList");

                      Food food = foodList[index];
                      return ListTile(
                          title:
                              Text(food.name, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30)),
                          subtitle: Text(
                            "Calories: ${food.calories}\nVegan: ${food.isVegan}",
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                          ),
                          onTap: () => showFoodDialog(context, food, index));
                    },
                    itemCount: foodList.length,
                    separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                        Divider(color: Colors.black),
                  );
                },
                listener: (BuildContext context, foodList) {},
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ]),
      ),



  class DrinkBloc extends Bloc<DrinkEvent, List<Drink>> {
  @override
  List<Drink> get initialState => List<Drink>();

  @override
  Stream<List<Drink>> mapEventToState(DrinkEvent event) async* {
    if (event is SetDrinks) {
      yield event.drinkList;
    } else if (event is AddDrink) {
      List<Drink> newState = List.from(state);
      if (event.newDrink != null) {
        newState.add(event.newDrink);
      }
      yield newState;
    } else if (event is DeleteDrink) {
      List<Drink> newState = List.from(state);
      newState.removeAt(event.drinkIndex);
      yield newState;
    } else if (event is UpdateDrink) {
      List<Drink> newState = List.from(state);
      newState[event.drinkIndex] = event.newDrink;
      yield newState;
    }
  }
}
```

Snippet:

```
body: BlocProvider(
    create: (BuildContext context) => DrinkBloc(),
    child: Column(children: [
      Row(
```

and the error I am getting now is basically when I click button to add a drink (the button next to the 'Drinks')

```
No ancestor could be found starting from the context that was passed to BlocProvider.of<DrinkBloc>().
The context used was: DrinkForm(state: _DrinkFormState#5d9c5)
BlocProvider.of() called with a context that does not contain a Bloc of type DrinkBloc.
```

How it looks like right now (the bottom part works, but the upper one, drinks, doesn't, maybe because I wrapped the whole thing inside the DrinkBloc, not sure how to change that
)

[image]

**main.dart**

```
   class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<FoodBloc>(
      create: (context) => FoodBloc(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Sqflite Tutorial',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.deepPurple,
        ),
        home: FoodList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe put the code in main in MultiBlocProvider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not providing/injecting `DrinkBloc` into the widget tree.

Therefore when you try to access `DrinkBloc` bloc, using BlocConsumer, it tries to look up its ancestors for that bloc. Since it is missing it'll throw that particular error  `BlocProvider.of() called with a context that does not contain a Bloc of type DrinkBloc.`

For providing/injecting `Drinkbloc` you can use the `BlocProvider` as follows:

```
BlocProvider(
  create: (BuildContext context) => BlocA(),
  child: ChildA(),
);
```

Call this anywhere as an ancestor of BlocConsumer.

E.g:

```
Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("FoodList")),
      body:  BlocProvider(
                 create: (BuildContext context) => DrinkBloc(),
               child: Column(children: [
                          ...
                          ],
         );
```

Comment: Is it possible to send whole code (just insert the one you sent me to the original code I linked), just so I can understand it a bit better? I'm sorry if it's too much trouble, I am still learning, so it's kinda tough to catch it all. @Joy Terence

Comment: @arbiter, No problem, just added a snippet to give you an idea where to place it

Comment: Okay, that worked, no more red screen, but I am still getting an issue, where it says that ``No ancestor could be found starting from the context that was passed to BlocProvider.of<DrinkBloc>()``, I added the Bloc code and the changed snippet and how it looks in the main post.

Comment: I changed it to be DrinkBloc, it's strange, the bottom part works (Food part), but the top part doesn't it produces the error (updated in the main post). Updated main post @Joy Terence

Comment: I see that you are routing to `DrinkForm` page on icon click. If you try `context.bloc<DrinkBloc>().add(...)` from there, that will fail due to context in `DrinkForm` being not aware. Go through this [github issue](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/74) to get an idea on who to achieve this. Especially [this comment](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/74#issuecomment-457969382)

Comment: Yeah, this is the snippet from the DrinkForm ``DatabaseProvider.db.insertDrink(drink).then(
                              (storedDrink) =>
                                  BlocProvider.of<DrinkBloc>(context).add(
                                AddDrink(storedDrink),
                              ),``

Comment: It might be an issue with the main.dart, I only have FoodBloc on there, I added it on main post (the last snippet of code)

Comment: @arbiter, yea it is. You need to provide `Drinkbloc` as well in your `main.dart`. Use [MultiBlocProvider](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_bloc/latest/flutter_bloc/MultiBlocProvider-class.html) to provide more than one bloc into the tree.

Comment: I added MultiProvider to the main, should work now, didn't have time to test it, but it looks something like below now, I think that should work, let me know if that looks good, I'll mark the answer, I appreciate your help tremendously.

Comment: ``class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider<FoodBloc>(
          create: (context) => FoodBloc(),
        ),
        BlocProvider<DrinkBloc>(
          create: (context) => DrinkBloc(),
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(``

Answer (score 0):

In order for the BlocConsumer to work the context, it's in should know about the bloc it uses, hence, `called with a context that does not contain a Bloc of type DrinkBloc.`

as in [flutter_bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc) docs you must define the provider like this

```
BlocProvider(
  create: (BuildContext context) => DrinkBloc(),
  child: Widget("this widget's context contains DrinkBloc"),
);
```

So just put this anywhere higher in the widget tree from where you want to and the BlocConsumer anywhere inside it.

Comment: As mentioned, I really appreciate your answers and will mark them all. Is it possible to send me code in context (add this BlocProvider to my code), just so I can see how it would work best, as mentioned, I'm still learning Flutter, so it would be best to see it in action. Basically I just want these Blocs to work one on top of the other (each in Expanded widget). @Khashayar Motarjemi